# Laravel using find() and get() together

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I have a table 'tour2s' with 2 rows and when I do:

```
$tour = Tour2::find(1);
dd($tour);
```

it returns the tour with 'id' = 1. And it's Object.

[image]

I want to turn the object to collection of only attributes of the model, nothing else. And I know that when I use ->get() it returns collection.

But when I am trying:

```
$tour = Tour2::find(1)->get();
dd($tour);
```

It returns a collection but of all 2 tour objects (full objects, not only attributes):
[image]

I did it like:

```
   $tour = Tour2::find(1);
   $tour = collect($tour);
   dd($tour);
```

and now it's what i what - it return a collection of only model attributes (WHAT I WANTED):

[image]

SO, my question is why when I used $tour=Tour2::find(1)->get() it returned all tours not only the one with 'id'=1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the main question, as i understand is: "Why when i wrote Tour2::find(1)->get() i receives collection of all records".

when you wrote Tour2::find(1) it assumes that you receive instanse of model Tour2. So we can simple write $tourInstanse->get()

If you go to \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model you can see that here is no method called get() but we have a magic method `__call`. Look at his implementation:

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (in_array($method, ['increment', 'decrement'])) {
            return $this->$method(...$parameters);
        }

        return $this->newQuery()->$method(...$parameters);
    }
```

So, when you call get() method on a model instance you get model`s QueryBuilder (as described in last row) and call get() method on a QueryBuilder. As a result, you receiving all records of that model Class.

Answer (score 2):

Passing an array to `find()` will return a collection.

```
$tour = Tour2::find([1]);
```

However, it will be a collection of Tour2 objects, not only the attributes.

Then, if you want only the attributes, you could use `$tour->toArray()`

You could also do `$tour = collect(Tour2::find(1));`

And to answer your question, when you use `$tour=Tour2::find(1)->get()`, Laravel fetch the first tour, and then calling get() on `$tour` will fetch all other records, so return two tours in your case.